# Cannot add "Done" button to CABTMIDICentralViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, bluetooth

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question, but I'm new to native iOS development and I've been searching for an answer for hours without any success.

I'm developing an application that requires connecting to a bluetooth MIDI keyboard. I found the following documentation on Apple's website, which describes how to manage bluetooth devices from an application https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1831/_index.html

I was able to display the dialog and connect to the keyboard using the following code. Problem is, there is no way to dismiss the dialog. For what I can see in the code the "Done" button is added but it doesn't display when running the application.

```
- (void)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)configureCentral:(id)sender
{
    CABTMIDICentralViewController *viewController = [CABTMIDICentralViewController new];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    // this will present a view controller as a popover in iPad and modal VC on iPhone
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                      target:self
                                                      action:@selector(doneAction:)];

    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popC = navController.popoverPresentationController;
    popC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popC.sourceRect = [sender frame];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    popC.sourceView = button.superview;

    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

CABTMIDICentralViewController itself as some controls to the navigation bar depending on the current status, not sure if it is overriding such button

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (for the iPhone version):

```
- (void)doneAction:(id)sender {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)configureCentral:(id)sender {

  CABTMIDICentralViewController *viewControllerBT = [CABTMIDICentralViewController new];

  UINavigationController *navControllerBT = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerBT];

  UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  btn.frame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width-60, 40, 60, 40);
  btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
  [btn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btn addTarget:self action: @selector(doneAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [navControllerBT.view addSubview:btn];

  [self presentViewController:navControllerBT animated:NO completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)configureLocalPeripheral:(UIButton *)sender {

  CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController *viewControllerBTA = [[CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController alloc] init];

  UINavigationController *navControllerBTA = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerBTA];

  UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  btn.frame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width-60, 40, 60, 40);
  btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
  [btn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btn addTarget:self action: @selector(doneAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [navControllerBTA.view addSubview:btn];

  [self presentViewController:navControllerBTA animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a bug where the view controller was overwriting any left button of the navigation bar. If I remember correctly, this was fixed in iOS 10.

Make sure that your storyboard has a navigation bar. This code relies on the fact that self is a UIViewController that has a UINavigationController.

Here is some code that works correctly for me:

```
- (IBAction)configureCentral:(UIButton*)sender {
    centralViewController = [[CABTMIDICentralViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: centralViewController animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)handleDone:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController *)presentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller viewControllerForAdaptivePresentationStyle:(UIModalPresentationStyle)style {
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(handleDone:)];
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)controller.presentedViewController;
    nav.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButton;

    return controller.presentedViewController;
}

- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
     return UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
}
```

You can use the same technique to show the `localPeripheralViewController`.